# Submit a trackback to arXiv - User-Agent issues

Tags: php, web, trackback

I would like to submit a trackback to [arXiv](http://arxiv.org) using the only php script available I found, [PHP Trackback](http://sourceforge.net/projects/phptrackback/).
However it seems like I am not able to proceed since I get a "HTTP 403 Forbidden" error. It further states:

> Sadly, your client does not supply a proper User-Agent, and is consequently excluded.

So, how can I include a User-Agent? As a guess I tried

```
fputs($tb_sock, "User-Agent: " . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\r\n");
```

inside the corresponding function in the above mentioned script. 
Hence my question:

**Is there a way to supply a User-Agent sending a trackback?**

Please note that I do not have any blogging software on webspace. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @Juhana for your encouraging comment. For this task a bash/perl script should do the job. Something like "send trackback.xml to blog" but I am lacking skills and insights on trackbacks to do it :)

Comment: Just a remark for all: arXiv simply doesn't accept my trackbacks, sad but true. It's some whitelist rule without further explanation...

Answer (score 1):

You were almost close, in fact, you have to edit the trackback_cls.php file and add this:

```
fputs($tb_sock, "User-Agent: trackback\r\n");
```

after:

```
fputs($tb_sock, "Host: " . $target["host"] . "\r\n");
```

Comment: Can you provide some context to your answer, that way future readers can learn how to apply it to their issues and not just in this situation.  I also highly recommend taking a read through http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer, using that link as a reference can greatly help the visibility and clarity of your answer.

Comment: I have precised my answer

Answer (score 0):

Did you check this page? http://arxiv.org/help/trackback/

arXiv does support trackbacks but only on pages with a url of the form `http://arxiv.org/abs/{paper_id}`